# as3 how to make movement smoother?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a WASD key movement for keydown. I want it to play an animation always when walking and always move when key is pressed.

The issue is, if I press multiple keys at once, it stops moving or stops the animation. Making it look stiff and unsmooth.

```
private function onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent): void
    {
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
        {
            vx = -5;
            play();
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
        {
            vx = 5;
            play();
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
        {
            vy = -5;
            play();
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
        {
            vy = 5;
            play();
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you mean by multiple keys at once is like W+D would be moving diagonal up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code you are using right now means if keyboard is pressed, onKeyDown will be triggered and check if it key A or D or W or S is pressed and it only handles one of them because of `else if`

try change your code like this

```
private function onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent): void
    {
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
        {
            vx = -5;
            play();
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
        {
            vx = 5;
            play();
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
        {
            vy = -5;
            play();
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
        {
            vy = 5;
            play();
        }
    }
```

if this doesn't solve your problem, maybe it is something on your `play()` function